# How to disable caching when using the time command?

Tags: time

When running time on process/application, it seems like it always cache the result/process, and thus doesn't give the `real` timing of the process.

I tried:

```
sync; time process
```

and

```
sync -f; time process
```

but it seems it doesn't really disable caching.

By running `time process` or as the above example `sync -f; time process`, `sync; time process` repeatedly, it can be noticed that the running time change (which i suspect is because of caching).

Any way to really disable caching to give real time of process?

Comment: Could you perhaps give some examples, or explain why you get the impression that a process took longer (or should take longer) than what `time` shows? Does the same effect happen with `time sleep 1`?

Comment: try to launch the command `time sleep 1` or even `time date` repeatedly, and you'll notice that the displayed time information change at some point (because as i suspect, of caching...). The same thing happen with the example i gave in my post (using sync/sync -f).

Comment: disabling caching/or just knowing the real running time of a process/application is very important, especially if you're making application yourself, which is why I'm asking (though the example i gave aren't things i made myself, but they illustrate what i mean).

Comment: The caching is not of the process. In is of disk access. Try the `nocache` tool it works as a command prefix in the same way that `time` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time` shows the resource usage for its child process, as measured by the kernel; it uses [`getrusage`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) to do so (on Linux, this is implemented using [`wait4`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html). It measures the real time used by the particular execution being measured.

Variations you see reflect variations which occur during process execution. They have a large variety of causes, typically involving resource contention of one kind or another. Like any benchmark, the use of `time` only makes sense in a pre-defined scenario.

Trying to measure the execution time of a command without any external influence is (mostly) possible, but it requires a lot of work to set up. On Linux, you can [flush all disk caches beforehand](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html?highlight=drop_caches#drop-caches):

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

(The effects of running a process aren’t cached anywhere else, except in CPU caches to a small extent, unless the process itself performed its own memoisation so that it will do less work if run again — *e.g.* a compiler with `ccache`. You’d presumably know whether your own application does this.)

You can also run the command you wish to measure on a dedicated CPU, otherwise unused by the kernel, so it won’t be affected by interrupts or rescheduling, and less affected by cache flushes. Other factors to bear in mind include CPU frequency variations, hyperthreading, address space randomisation...

One of my colleagues, Victor Stinner, has written up [his notes and links on the topic of benchmarking](https://vstinner.readthedocs.io/benchmark.html), focusing on Python benchmarking; one link which provides a good set of adjustments to make is [Denis Bakhvalov’s guide to getting consistent results on Linux](https://easyperf.net/blog/2019/08/02/Perf-measurement-environment-on-Linux).

Comment: Nicely detailed post! Didn't knew the bit about `ccache` and space randomisation, and the linked post are also well written.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling dirty caches completely though it may lead to quite unpleasant effects, i.e. your write speed could be severely affected because they allow the kernel to optimize write operations, e.g.:

```
sudo sysctl vm.dirty_background_bytes=4096
sudo sysctl vm.dirty_bytes=8192
```

A good write up on caching: https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/

Comment: The two command you mentioned seems to throw the same error: `sysctl: setting key "vm.dirty_background_bytes": Invalid argument` `sysctl: setting key "vm.dirty_bytes": Invalid argument`

Comment: I'm using linux :)! Ubuntu 19.04 to be precise.

Comment: @NordineLotfi Sorry, looks like setting 0 is not supported, 4096 is the minimum. :-)

Comment: This time it seems to work for `sudo sysctl vm.dirty_background_bytes=4096` but not the other one (have the same error as i posted above).

Comment: Try `8192`. Looks like there's a limit on how low you can go :-) 4096 and 8192 work here.

Comment: Yep, works! though it doesn't resolve the problem i described in my post.

Comment: These settings should definitely help you get better results. Disabling write caching in Linux seems impossible and it's also detrimental to the system performance.

Comment: Hey @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've been looking for I/O Disk specialists out there, this seems to be an area of Linux with very limited amount of people with expertise in the subject. Can you help me with my latest question? You can see it on my profile. I'm getting very very close to diagnosing what the root of the problem is (application performance suffers when under conditions of heavy disk swapping, while it doesn't happen in a different distro, same hardware...) See the commens in my question to read the updates I've been posting.